# Update column depending on the current value

Tags: php, mysql

I have the **reminders** table similar to this:

```
|id |event_id |reminder            |
|---|---------|--------------------|
|37 | 75      |2015-10-19 11:00:00 |
|38 | 75      |2015-10-22 10:45:00 |
|39 | 76      |2015-10-23 11:00:00 |
|40 | 76      |2015-10-24 11:30:00 |
```

There is a primary key on column **id**. I need to update the **reminder** column so that I will get its current value, do some conversion using a php function and return the new value. Thus, the new value is not the same for all records, but depends on its previous value.

For example, this will not work, but I'd like something like that:

```
$sql = "UPDATE reminders r
        SET r.reminder = '". my_function("r.reminder") ."' ";
```

My question is how can I get the current value of the reminder column and forward to a php function as a parameter. Is it possible with a single query, and how? If not, what is the best way to do that?

I hope I don't have to put the update statement within a loop and update each row separately, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You'd have to `SELECT id, event_id, reminder FROM your_table`, load everything to php (an array perhaps) call your function for each element and then send your update(s) back do mysql

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can replicate the desired function in SQL, this will not be possible as a single query. Ultimately a query is just a simple string that gets sent off to the database without any further interaction from PhP.

If you must run a PhP function on the code, you'll need to do something like this.

```
$qResult = $mysqli->query($sql);
$results = $qResult->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $mysqli->query("UPDATE myTable SET someColumn = someNewValue WHERE id = " . $result['id'] . ";");
}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll do what you said, but I was just wondering if there was another way.

Comment: Like I said, it is possible if your function can have its output replicated as a SQL function. Perhaps that would be a more apt question, instead. If you post your PhP function, it may be able to be determined if it can be converted.